# batch UPDATE autoload value in wp_options table

Tags: database, options, optimization

After running the following query `SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';` I've found I got **1587** autoloading options values, mostly belonging to custom fields values; since they start with `category` or `_category` I am looking for a way to SELECT and UPDATE the autoload value for all at once. I guess an SQL query would be the fasted method but I am not sure about the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Not a hard task at the end. I've managed to do it in two chunks with

`UPDATE wp_options SET autoload = 'no' WHERE option_name LIKE 'category%';` and 
`UPDATE wp_options SET autoload = 'no' WHERE option_name LIKE '_category%';`

Comment: Hi i wonder is there any benefit on this?

Comment: @MichaelRogers Yes sure, if you have plenty of autoloaded options which increase SQL data transfers - it might have a positive effect.